# Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted in xampp

Tags: xampp, port

Sometime before all thing is working properly in xampp, but now whenever I try to open phpMyadmin it will throw **Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted** in xampp error.
Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query exception laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733111/query-exception-laravel-5-4)